# GET method executing before POST method after a page submit?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

After editing a form and clicking a Save button, the HttpGet method is being executed before the HttpPost method. The page is reloading with the query string in the URL, and the old data still populating the fields, but the data has been saved on the server side. If I remove the query string and reload the page, the new data appears.

My expectation is that only the HttpPost method would be called, changes would be saved saved, then the page would be loaded back up with the saved changes.

Using the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0` package.

Here are my `HttpGet` and `HttpPost` methods:

```
[HttpGet]
    [Route("~/Home/Activity/{activityId}")]
    public IActionResult Activity(int activityId)
    {
        ViewData["Title"] = "Activity Detail";


        FundraiserDBContext context = new FundraiserDBContext(_ServerName, EnvironmentCode);
        Engagement activity;

        if (activityId == -1)
        {
            activity = new Engagement();
            context.Engagement.Add(activity);
        }
        else
        {
            activity = context.Engagement.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == activityId);
        }

        if (activity != null)
        {
            ActivityViewModel vmActivity = new ActivityViewModel(activity, context);
            return View("Activity", vmActivity);
        }
        else
        {
            ActivityViewModel vmActivity = new ActivityViewModel(context);
            return View("Activity", vmActivity);
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    //[Route("~/Home/Activity/{activityId}")]
    public IActionResult Activity(ActivityViewModel vmActivity)
    {
        FundraiserDBContext db = new FundraiserDBContext(_ServerName, EnvironmentCode);

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Engagement.Update(vmActivity.ToEngagement(db));
            db.SaveChanges();                
        }

        return View("Activity", vmActivity); //this was vm.EngagementId
    }
```

And here is the code for the Save button:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn-success pull-right" style="width:80px;" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Activity", "Home", @Model)'">Save</button>
```

Comment: Where do you call POST method, `onclick` you are invoking GET request

Comment: That was it. I didn't need the onclick at all. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matjaž Mav found my error and described it in the comment below the original post. I mistakenly thought I needed the onclick event on my button. Removing this resulted in the expected behavior I was looking for.

The button code now looks like this:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn-success pull-right" style="width:80px;">Save</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove redirect from post method, because before returning the `View` its redirecting to the `Index` method without updated model

```
Redirect($"~/Home/Index"); // remove this line
```

Comment: @CoreyD you have removed it now in your question, is it remain same ?

Comment: That line was part of my troubleshooting, my mistake. Removing it results in same behavior as described.